# CodeBuild Customization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Is it possible to customize **Build History** details in codebuild project. I would like to append some extra info (through buildspec.yml maybe)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted portion is build id which is a combination of project name and build identifier. Unfortunately there is no way to modify this information through any API call.

Comment: Can we modify Source Version

Comment: Source version is auto resolved, it will be s3 object version for s3 source or commit id for a CodeCommit/Github source.